# Parcelamento para mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um sistema de vendas no qual 1 venda gera 12 parcelas para 3 usuários, sendo eles o vendedor, o gerente e o supervisor, gostaria de saber qual o melhor método para o armazenamento destas parcelas.

Seria criar 1 tabela para cada usuário e quando fizesse a venda gerasse as 36 linhas, um *cronjob* que gerasse as parcelas a cada mês ou outra coisa?

É um sistema para mais ou menos 100 usuários.

Comment: Está um pouco confuso, pode explicar melhor? Afinal, são 12 parcelas ou 36? Seja como for, criar uma tabela por usuário é uma péssima ideia, crie uma tabela só com uma coluna indicando qual é o usuário.

Comment: @bfavaretto são 3 tipos de usuários sendo eles (vendedor, gerente e supervisor) cada venda gera 12 parcelas para cada 1 deles com valores diferentes. por ex: 1 vendedor faz uma venda, desta venda 1.7% é comissão do vendedor, 0.3% é comissão do supervisor e 1.5 é comissão do gerente. e caso esta venda seja por indicação de algum cliente tem mais a comissão do cliente

Comment: @KelvinPrimo isso são duas coisas distintas, tipo de usuário tem de ser uma tabela "tipo" com id na tabela de usuários: `tipo_id` ou assim. depois cada id de usuário tem de estar na tabela de vendas: `usuario_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa muito longe. No caso você pode usar 3 tabelas simples, como ver nesse diagrama ER bem porco que acabei de fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: então, esta ideia era o que eu estava tentando evitar, pois em 1 ano nas melhores hipóteses já teria 360000 rows a tabela de comissionamento. entre eles as inadimplentes.

Comment: Até ai tudo bem. Mysql dá conta sem problemas desse número de registros. O que vc poderia fazer ai é criar 2 views. Uma para parcela casas e outra para inadimplentes se vc quer uma forma fácil de separa-las.

Comment: Se seguir com esse modelo você também pode particionar a tablea. Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-partition.php  Com ele faz separações lógicas e fisicas dos registros, de acordo com a forma com a qual vc quiser odernar (ano por exempo).

Comment: eu tive a seguinte ideia a pouco, gostaria da sua opinião, quando o usuário confirmasse o pagamento da 1 parcela, o sistema geraria a segunda. e isso sucessivamente.

Comment: Entendi, vc quer gerar conforme é paga. Funciona, mas dificultaria na hora que vc por exemplo precisasse procurar por inadimplentes por exemplo. Mas tudo depende das operações que você pretende fazer. Mas lembre-se o numero de registros da tabela não é importante desde que você use corretamente indices e chavs. Normalmente tabelas que tendem a crescer muito, eu também evito usar INT ou BIGINT como chave primária, preferindo um GUID.

Comment: huum, entendi. vou seguir seu conselho e caso o banco fique muito grande ai tem que partir para partição. muito obrigado.